# C++:Copy reg_iterator to a vector in order to sort() and unique()?

Tags: c++

I have about half a million entries in my regex_iterator and there will be duplicates. In order for me to sort() and unique() on the regex_iterator (which itself does not take much time), I need to copy it to a vector which takes a lot of time(about 20 seconds). My code applies regex on file content (string fcontent) and adds the matches to a vector one by one using push_back.

```
vector<string> vthread;
std::regex e(R"(\{\w+:\d\})", std::regex::ECMAScript|std::regex::icase);
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rit(fcontent.begin(), fcontent.end(), e);
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;
while (rit != rend) {
    vthread.push_back(rit->str());
    ++rit;
}
std::sort(vthread.begin(),vthread.end());
vthread.erase(unique(vthread.begin(),vthread.end()),vthread.end());
```

Where the push_back above is more cpu consuming as well as time-consuming. Looking for an alternative and efficient approach. can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `regex_iterator` is lazy. The construction of `rit` only finds the first match and `++rit` finds the subsequent matches. I doubt that `push_back` is a bottleneck.

The call to `rit->str()` is allocating a new string copied from `fcontent`, this could be avoided if you use `rit->position()` and `rit->length()` to build a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (C++17) instead.

Comment: Thanks, @kmdreko! Give me some time to read more on constructing string_view (I am relatively new to C++) and see the performance improvement margin. Marking answer as accepted anyway.